# Get selected value from string, from point to point

Tags: ruby

please is in ruby possible to get information from example name `"Doe,Jon"` (exact format) to get only the name `"Jon"`? Of course the name can be always different, I was thinking if is not possible to get the value from end of string to "," separator. If is it possible, how?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `"Doe,Jon".split(',').last`

Comment: `"Doe,Jon".gsub(/.*,/, '')`

Comment: `"Doe,Jon".slice(("Doe,Jon".index(',')+1)..-1)`

Comment: `"Doe,Jon"[/(\w+)$/]`

Comment: `"Doe,Jon"[/(\w+),(\w+)/, 2]`

Comment: `require "csv"; CSV.parse("John,Doe")[0][1]`

Comment: `”My,friend,Joe”[/[^,]+\z/]`.

Comment: @Thang, perhaps use `rindex` in case there is more than one comma.

Answer (score 1):

So lets examine some of the solutions that are given to you in the comments

### Split

```
"Doe,Jon".split(',').last

# or a bit more verbose

parts = "Doe,Jon".split(',') # ["Doe", "Jon"]
name = parts.last # "Jon"
```

`String#split` splits a sting into an array. It uses the parameter `","` as separator. `Array#last` returns the last item from an array.

### Gsub

```
"Doe,Jon".gsub(/.*,/, '')
```

`String#gsub` substitutes the part that matches the Regular Expression (`/.*,/`) with the substitution value (`""`).
The regexp matches everything (`.*`) up to (and including) the comma. And the replacement is an empty string, essentially deleting the part that matches the regexp.
Note that you could/should probably have an anchor to make the regexp more strict (`/\A.*,/`)

### Slice

`String#slice` creates a substring given a range. `-1` is a shortcut for the last element.
`String#index` finds the index of a character inside a String.

```
"Doe,Jon".slice(("Doe,Jon".index(',')+1)..-1)

# or more verbose
full = "Doe,Jon"
index_of_comma = full.index(',') # => 3
index_after_comma = index + 1
name = full.slice(index_after_comma..full.size)
```

### CSV

CSV (Comma Separated Values) is a format where multiple values are separated by a comma (or other separation character).

```
require "csv"
CSV.parse("John,Doe")[0][1]
```

This will treat the name as CSV data and then access the first row of data (´[0]´). And from that row accesses the second element (`[1]`) which is the name.

### Now what?

There are usually multiple ways to reach a goal. And it's up to you to pick a way. I'd go with the first one. To me it is easy to read and understand its purpose.